# Intl.DateTimeFormat returns wrong month name once

Tags: javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/prd9Lz18/11

March is being returned twice. Does anyone know why? I'm using a different solution right now (array with names of month), but I'm really curious why this is happening and I feel like it's not on my end.

```js
let date = new Date();
let month = date.getMonth();
let options = { month: "long" };

for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  if (month === 12) {
    month = 0;
  }
  date.setMonth(month);
  let monthName = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", options).format(date);
  console.log((month + 1) + " " + monthName);
  month++;
}
```

Comment: Set the day to 01. The `new Date()` captures today, and today is 30. so 30th of february is interpreted as March, so it prints twice. Just fix the day and you'ĺl be fine.

Comment: Thanks. I was a bit lost because it had been working fine earlier.

Comment: By the way, @User863 wrote a code solution to solve your problem. If you feel like his answer is correct and will help others in the future, mark it as answer. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dayValue` option (represents the day of the month) from `setMonth()`

> `dateObj.setMonth(monthValue[, dayValue])`

```js
let date = new Date();
let month = date.getMonth();
let options = { month: "long" };

for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  if (month === 12) {
    month = 0;
  }
  date.setMonth(month, 1); // dayValue - 1
  let monthName = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", options).format(date);
  console.log((month + 1) + " " + monthName);
  month++;
}
```